# How to explode pandas and add new rows and columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
start   stop    speaker_label   y
309.16  309.58         2       5
312.01  312.59         2       5
313.4   313.59         1       4
314.35  314.92         2       4
316.96  317.27         1       5
319.36  319.89         1       5
322.01  323.10         2       7
```

I want to transform this dataframe in a few ways:

- Convert each row to represent 1 second. `start` and `stop` represent the time (in seconds) that an event occurs. I want to explode this so that that I get 1 row per second. When converting floats to int, I want to round dow.
- I want to create 2 new columsn, `y1` and `y2`, which come from a cross between the `speaker_label` and `y` columns. If `speaker_label` 1 is `5` at `y`, then column `y1` for that row is 5.
- If there are rows of seconds that do not fall within a `start` `stop` range and therefor have no `speaker_label` or `y` data, then I want the values to be NaN.

It should look like this:

```
time    y1  y2
309    NaN  5
310    NaN  5
311    NaN  5
312    NaN  5
313    4    NaN
314    NaN  4
315    NaN  4
316    5    NaN
317    5    NaN
318    5    NaN
319    5    NaN
320    NaN  NaN
321    NaN  NaN
322    NaN  7
323    NaN  7
```

If the `speaker_label` value changes (1 for 311.01 and 2 for 311.99), then the `speaker_label` value for 1 will go to `y1` and the speaker_label value for 2 will go to `y2`. If the `speaker_label` value does not change in this circumstance, then assign the `y` value at 311.01 to 311 and not consider the 311.99 `y` value. I added this circumstance to the OP.

Comment: Would there ever be overlap with two events within the same second? Or what if something ends at, say, 311.01 and the next one starts at 311.99?

Comment: Yes, that could happen. If the `speaker_label` value changes (1 for 311.01 and 2 for 311.99), then the `speaker_label` value for 1 will go to `y1` and the speaker_label value for 2 will go to `y2`. If the `speaker_label` value does not change in this circumstance, then assign the `y` value at 311.01 to 311 and not consider the 311.99 `y` value. I added this circumstance to the OP.

Comment: Given the sample input, why isn't `y2=NaN` for 310/311/315 in the expected output? Is that related to the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the bullet requirements, you can [**`explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [**`pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), and [**`reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

1. [**`explode()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the `start`–`stop` intervals into `time` rows:

```py
df['time'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(int(x.start), 1+int(x.stop)), axis=1)
df = df.explode('time').drop(columns=['start', 'stop']).set_index('time')

#       speaker_label  y
# time                  
# 309               2  5
# 312               2  5
# 313               1  4
# 314               2  4
# 316               1  5
# 317               1  5
# 319               1  5
# 322               2  7
# 323               2  7
```

2. Pivot into `y` columns using [**`pivot_table()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index='time', columns='speaker_label')

#        y     
#        1    2
# time
# 309    NaN  5.0
# 312    NaN  5.0
# 313    4.0  NaN
# 314    NaN  4.0
# 316    5.0  NaN
# 317    5.0  NaN
# 319    5.0  NaN
# 322    NaN  7.0
# 323    NaN  7.0
```

3. [**`reindex()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the missing `time` steps:

```py
df = df.reindex(range(df.index.min(), 1+df.index.max()))

#        y     
#        1    2
# time
# 309    NaN  5.0
# 310    NaN  NaN
# 311    NaN  NaN
# 312    NaN  5.0
# 313    4.0  NaN
# 314    NaN  4.0
# 315    NaN  NaN
# 316    5.0  NaN
# 317    5.0  NaN
# 318    NaN  NaN
# 319    5.0  NaN
# 320    NaN  NaN
# 321    NaN  NaN
# 322    NaN  7.0
# 323    NaN  7.0
```

Note that this doesn't match your expected output exactly, but it's how I interpreted the bullet requirements. This method puts NaNs when neither `speaker_label` is active. I couldn't figure out why your expected output put values in some of those cases.